# Oracle version 12c Default account

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to access default Database from Oracle 12c but Oracle 12c not accessing by default Username Scott and Password Tiger, Why?. While 11g provide the access.

Comment: Did you unlock `SCOTT` account ?

Comment: What is the error?  Did you install the sample schemas (of which `scott` is one)?  Did you unlock the `scott` account?

Comment: "Why?"  -- Who knows?  If it failed to connect, it gave an error message.  Something like ORA-nnnn.  If we knew the error message, we could give a definitive answer, or at least be able to refine the questions needed to run it down.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC001)

> When you install Oracle Database with the Oracle Universal Installer,
>   the sample schemas are installed by default if you select the Basic
>   Installation option. Selecting the sample schemas option installs all
>   sample schemas (HR, OE, PM, SH, IX) in the database. If you choose not
>   to install the sample schemas at that time, you can add them later by
>   following the instructions in section "Manually Installing Sample
>   Schemas".
>
> At the end of the installation process, a dialog box displays the
>   accounts that have been created and their lock status. By default, all
>   sample schemas are locked and their passwords are expired. Before you
>   can use a locked account, you must unlock it and reset its password.
>   You can unlock the accounts at this point in the installation process.
>   Alternatively, after the installation completes, you can unlock the
>   schemas and reset their passwords by using the ALTER USER ... ACCOUNT
>   UNLOCK statement.